# How to make a proper call from Android to a non-static function in Java? (Cocos2Dx in the mix)

Tags: android, android-activity, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, non-static

So I'm developing a small project with Cocos2Dx but I'm trying to add Bluetooth functionality, and that implies calling a non-static method to be able to access the Main Activity's association to the Android API. Almost everything that I've seen tells me to follow this procedure:
- Create an instance of the main activity (environment->NewGlobalRef is the one I'm using)
- Get method from activity and execute it (environment->GetObjectClass)

And here's the code. In java we have the following (omitting logical stuff like onCreate, onResume, etc):

```
public class TSP extends Cocos2dxActivity{
    public void CnxAttempt(){
         Log.e("TSP_BT","aTTEMPTING!");
    }
}
```

That's it! Just for now, I only want to show a Log message, confirming that the function is executed. Now, the fun part is at C++:

```
    static JNIEnv* getJNIEnv(void){
    JNIEnv *env = 0;

    // get jni environment
    if (gJavaVM->GetEnv((void**)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK){
        CCLog("Failed to get the environment using GetEnv()");
    }

    if (gJavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, 0) < 0){
        CCLog("Failed to get the environment using AttachCurrentThread()");
    }

    return env;
}
typedef struct JniMethodInfo_{
        JNIEnv *    env;        // The environment
        jclass      classID;    // classID
        jmethodID   methodID;   // methodID
    } JniMethodInfo;            // Struct that stores most of the important information to relate to Java code

    static bool getMethodInfo(JniMethodInfo &methodinfo, const char *methodName, const char *paramCode){
        jmethodID methodID = 0;
        JNIEnv *pEnv = 0;
        jobject methodObject = NULL;

        bool bRet = false;

        do {
            pEnv = getJNIEnv();
            if (! pEnv){
                CCLog("getMethodInfo -- pEnv false");
                break;
            }

            jclass localRef = pEnv->FindClass("org/cocos2dx/tsp/TSP");
            if (localRef == NULL) {
                CCLog("getMethodInfo -- localRefCls false");
                 break; // exception thrown 
            }

            gCallbackObject = pEnv->NewGlobalRef(localRef);
            if (gCallbackObject == NULL){
                CCLog("getMethodInfo -- CallbackOBJ false");
                break;
            }

            jclass classID = pEnv->GetObjectClass(methodObject);
            if (!classID){
                CCLog("getMethodInfo -- classID false");
                break;
            }

            methodID = pEnv->GetMethodID(classID, methodName, paramCode);
            if (!methodID){
                CCLog("getMethodInfo -- methodID false");
                break;
            }
            methodinfo.classID = classID;
            methodinfo.env = pEnv;
            methodinfo.methodID = methodID;
            CCLog("getMethodInfo -- methodinfo created");
            bRet = true;
        } while(0);

        return bRet;
    }

    void CnxAttempt(){
        JniMethodInfo methodInfo; // Creating a JniMethodInfo object to store all the data

        if (! getMethodInfo(methodInfo, "CnxAttempt", "()V")){
            CCLog("getMethodInfo is FALSE :(");
            return;
        }
        methodInfo.env->CallVoidMethod(methodObject,methodInfo.methodID);
        methodInfo.env->DeleteLocalRef(methodInfo.classID);
    }
```

And that's it! While calling CnxAttempt on C++, it goes BOOM because it doesn't recognise the method within the Java class and can't get to it...
Can someone give me a hand? If something is not clear please let me know. Thanks a bunch in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new global reference does **does not** create a new object. The difference between local and global references (from the docs) is:

> Local references are valid for the duration of a native method call, and are automatically freed after the native method returns. Global references remain valid until they are explicitly freed.

If you want to call a non-static method to an object you need to either pass the object to the native method (if it exists - shouldn't the main activity already exist?), create a new one using the NewObject* functions, or by calling some factory method.

Then get the class object of the object, get the methodID and then call the method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually stopped using the NewGlobalRef function and started using NewObject, but the results where the same. After some more research on the subject and several tweaks on the code, I managed to get to the non-static function, by altering the order of the definitions, following this example: [link](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java/2004-02/0570.html)
What I have to face now is that any kind of use of external functions(like Bluetooth) from the main activity will crash my app like a snap :( 
But that's for another question...maybe.
Thanks a lot!